# Flutter carousel_slider change images array by button click

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have 3 buttons, every buttons have image arrays, i need change carousel items on button clicked.
Now I have implemented it through tabs, but it loads the application very heavily, the animation becomes slow, as if the FPS falls.
Want to use only one slider and change its content when clicking on the buttons. But I didn't find it in the carousel api.

My code:

```
final List < String > imgList = [
    'assets/category/pubg.png',
    'assets/category/sparta.jpg',
    'assets/category/stormfall-age-of-war.jpg',
    'assets/category/warface.jpg',
    'assets/category/warface-logo.jpg',
    'assets/category/playstation.png'
];

final List < Widget > imageSliders = imgList
    .map((item) => Container(
        child: Container(
            //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                child: Stack(
                    children: < Widget > [
                        Image.asset(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
                        Positioned(
                            bottom: 0.0,
                            left: 0.0,
                            right: 0.0,
                            child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: < Widget > [
                                    Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                            'Slide # ${imgList.indexOf(item)}',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                                    fontSize: 16,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                            'Slide # ${imgList.indexOf(item)}',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: const Color(0xFFA5ABC8),
                                                    fontSize: 12,
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ],
                            ),
                        ),
                    ],
                )),
        ),
    ))
    .toList();


CarouselSlider(
    options: CarouselOptions(
        autoPlay: false,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        viewportFraction: 0.6,
        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
            setState(() {
                _current = index;
            });
        }
    ),
    items: imageSliders,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

import the package file

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
```

Initialize a controller,

```
  CarouselController carouselController = CarouselController();
```

Provide this controller to your carousel,

```
CarouselSlider(carouselController:carouselController,
followed by your code),
```

And add the below line to your button onTap or onPressed event:

```
carouselController.animateToPage(image_index);
```